# Having trouble taking form data and putting into array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to push data from a form into an array. I have refresh disabled to allow console.log to show data sets. not sure what I am doing wrong here in my javascript file.

EDIT: ADDING MY VALIDATION CODE FOR CLARIFICATION

```
class Validate{
  constructor(){
      console.log("Validate started")
      this.formData = [];
      document.querySelector("#addbtn").addEventListener("click", e=>this.onClick(e));
  }

  onClick(e){
      const data = document.querySelectorAll("input");
      if(this.validateForm(data)){
          e.preventDefault();
          data.forEach(e=>{
              this.formData.push(e.value);
          })
      } else{
          console.log("form not valid");
      }
      
  }

  validateForm(formData){
      let validate = true;
      formData.forEach(e=>{
          if(!e.checkValidity())
          {
              validate = false;
          }
      })
      return validate
  }
}

(()=>{
  const validation = new Validate

})();


class Hero{

constructor(name,email,fanyears,reason){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.fanyears = fanyears;
    this.reason = reason;
    this.totalfanyears = Utility.calculateyears(this.fanyears);
  //  this.total = total;
  }

  
}

class Main{
  constructor(){
    this.listOfHeroes = [];
    document.querySelector("#addbtn").addEventListener("click",(e)=>this.add(e));
    document.querySelector("#displaybtn").addEventListener("click",(e)=>this.display(e));
  }

  add(e){
    // get data from form
    // create a hero from data
    // put that hero in the hero array
    let name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
    let email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    let fanyears = Number(document.querySelector("#fanyears").value);
    let reason = document.querySelector("#reason").value;
    let hero = new Hero(name,email,fanyears,reason,totalfanyears);
    
    this.listOfHeroes.push(hero);
  }


  display(e){
    for(let i=0; i<this.listOfHeroes.length;i++){
      //inner html would go here to put onto web page
        console.log(this.listOfHeroes)
    }
  }
}

(()=>{

  const main = new Main();
})();
```

I will also add my HTML form container code here below :

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class = "main">
    <form id = "heroForm">
      <h3> Super Hero Form </h3>
        <label for="name">
          Name:
        <input name="name"id="name" placeholder="Hero name" type ="text" required>
      </label>
      <label for="email">
        Email:
        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" type ="email" required>
      </label>
      <label for="fanyears">
        what year did you become a fan?
        <input name="fanyears"id="fanyears" placeholder="Amount" type ="number" min=1938 max=2022 step=1 required>
      </label>
      <label for="reason">
        Your reason?     
        <input name="reason" id="reason" placeholder="Enter info" type ="text" required>
      </label>
      
        
        <button type="submit" id="addbtn">Add hero</button>
        <button type="button" id="displaybtn">Display All</button>
        
        </form>
      <p id ="message" style = opacity:0>Hero added</p>
    </div>
  <article class="main">
    <h3> Display Results </h3>
    <p>
      
    </p>
  </article>  
</div>
```

Very confused on how to resolve this or where I am messing up. I have validation that works just fine without this and able to register proper values. regardless of the accuracy of validation not able to retain data and push into the array.

When i do it through my validation fields queryselectorall it works fine pushing into the array.

Comment: Where is `totalfanyears` defined and why are you passing it to `new Hero`? Where is `listOfHeroes` defined? You should probably learn the difference between variables and properties, i.e. when to use `this`. `console.log(this.listOfHeroes)` doesn’t make a lot of sense. Did you mean `console.log(this.listOfHeroes[i])`? The method can be rewritten as `display(){ this.listOfHeroes.forEach((hero) => console.log(hero)); }`. Instead of `Number`, you can just get the [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) for `<input type="number">`.

Comment: The default behavior of a button in a form is to submit that form to the server.  That will cause any html to be reloaded, and any javascript variables to be lost.  If that sounds like your problem, you can try adding `e.preventDefault()` to your button press handlers.

Comment: @James I added my validation code which includes this.

Comment: @SebastianSimon honestly was trying to follow a lecture the best to piece this all together variables are declared versus a property would be among a class constructor treated as a blueprint to reused is my understanding. let me know If I am missing anything more!

Comment: @TyeKillough Basically, yes. More importantly, properties are key–value entries on a specific object, such as an instance of your class. `listOfHeroes` is a property of `this`, so writing `listOfHeroes` when you actually need `this.listOfHeroes` is not possible (unless another variable has been declared like `const listOfHeroes = this.listOfHeroes;`).